# Gradle processResources for Spring Boot application.yml and select property to expand

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a gradle.properties which specifies the version

```
version=0.1.0
```

I want to expand the version in my Spring Boot application.yml below, however, I don't want to expand all properties, e.g. such as the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE variable and various other ones.  Some of those values are injected from a Kubernetes build tool.

```
spring:  
  profiles:
    active: ${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}
  application:
    version: ${version}
```

I know I can use the gradle task to do the entire file.

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("application.yml") {
      expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

But is there a way to filter and only expand the version?